# Rosin thresholding (Unimodal thresholding) JAVA

Tags: java, image-processing, threshold

I have to do for my project many image filters (all you can imagine) in JAVA (I use JAVA JAI). I have done all except unimodal thresholding by Paul L. Rosin. I found only this [document](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Paul.Rosin/resources/papers/simple2.pdf) and implementation on [c++](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Paul.Rosin/resources/unimodal/). Unfortunately, I'm terrible in c ++. Can you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: I can implement Rosin Threshold in Catalano Framework if you need

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Catalano Framework](https://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/). It's very easy and fast. There's a lot of examples in samples folder.

```
import Catalano.Imaging.Filters;
// If you want to use parallel processing. Change the namespace for:
// import Catalano.Imaging.Concurrent.Filters;

FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(bufferedImage);
fb.toGrayscale();

RosinThreshold rosin = new RosinThreshold();
rosin.applyInPlace(fb);
```